# RegEx to allow letters numbers and spaces but not two spaces in a row

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Hello I have a RegEx that allows up to 18 characters with numbers, letters and spaces only.

How can I modify this to check if the string is starting with a space, or has two spaces in a row?

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z\s]{1,18}$/
```

I am using this regex in both native javascript (not jquery) and PHP.

Comment: It’s really easier if you do a separate check for this, non-regex …

Comment: When you say two spaces in a row, do you mean anywhere in the string?

Comment: Note that `\s` [does not match *spaces only*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: add the `+` after the `}` or somewhere in there?

Comment: Please provide some test cases. Match or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if the string starts with a space or has 2 or more consecutive spaces, something like:

```
^(?!.*\s{2,})(?!^ )[0-9A-Za-z\s]{1,18}$
```

Comment: would the proposed regex select `" testerert  12v3k8"` or `" hey is  this fine"` which starts with a white space and has two white spaces in a row and in total 18 characters?

Comment: "You can use a negative look-ahead to check if the string starts with a space or has 2 or more consecutive spaces.." So why wouldn't it select " hey is  this fine" quote..? (there are 2 white spaces between "is" and "this" just this textarea converts double white spaces to single...)

Comment: because it starts with a space

Comment: last time i checked 1||1 was 1

Comment: I'm not following you, please test the strings here https://regex101.com/r/oK4qK9/2

Comment: @PedroLobito why (?!^ ) though?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(?![ ]{2}).)+
```

use this regex. This may solve your problem.